# Rundeck - PowerShell exit code

Tags: windows, powershell, rundeck

I have a script that check if a list of paths exist in windows instances with powershell.

The code:

```
$args[0].Split(",") | ForEach {
     if ($(Test-Path "$_")){
         echo "True -> $_" >> C:\Temp\check_paths_status;
     }else{
         echo "False -> $_" >> C:\Temp\check_paths_status;
     }
}

if ((Get-Content "C:\Temp\check_paths_status" | select-string -pattern "False").length -EQ 0) {
    rm C:\Temp\check_paths_status;
    echo "All OK";
    exit 0
}else{
    Get-Content "C:\Temp\check_paths_status" | select-string -pattern "False";
    rm C:\Temp\check_paths_status;
    exit 1 ### Here is the problem
}
```

the script it's called by Rundeck and pass the list of paths to comprobe
.\script.ps1 C:,C:\NonVAlidPath

The script works ok but no make correct exit's code, i recived this error:

```
<Objs Version="1.1.0.1" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/powershell/2004/04"><S S="Error">At C:\WINDOWS\TEMP\8323799-21235593-script.tmp.ps1:1 char:1_x000D__x000A_</S>

<S S="Error">+ [OutputType([System.boolean])]_x000D__x000A_</S><S S="Error">+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~_x000D__x000A_</S>
<S S="Error">Unexpected attribute 'OutputType'._x000D__x000A_</S><S S="Error">    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParseException_x000D__x000A_</S><S S="Error">    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnexpectedAttribute_x000D__x000A_</S><S S="Error"> _x000D__x000A_</S></Objs>

Failed: NonZeroResultCode: [pyWinRMexe] Result code: 1
Execution failed: 21235593 in project *********: [Workflow result: , step failures: {1=Dispatch failed on 1 nodes: [*********: NonZeroResultCode: [pyWinRMexe] Result code: 1]}, Node failures: {***********=[NonZeroResultCode: [pyWinRMexe] Result code: 1]}, status: failed]
```

Thank you very much for support.

** And excuse my poor English.

Comment: Set the invocation string (powershell.exe) and shell script extension (.ps1) in your job, take a look at this: https://github.com/rundeck-plugins/py-winrm-plugin/issues/21#issuecomment-480894071

Comment: Often times when there's a control application running powershell scripts you have to exit and express codes like this: `[system.environment]::Exit(1)`

Answer (score 0):

In PowerShell, you normally use `throw` or `write-error` to indicate a failed execution. If you just want to return a value describing the state of the run, use `return $value`

`Exit` will *terminate* the session.